# Unable to use less than or greater inside java script in xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I want to write the if condition by using greater than or less than symbol inside java script in xsl. I used like this '<' , but getting SyntaxError: missing ) after condition in the html.

Please share your suggestions.

```
<![CDATA[
    if(1 < 1){
        alert('yes');
    }else{
        alert('no');
    };
]]>
```

Comment: Suggestion: escape that character or use a `CDATA` section.

Comment: Please see my edits, i tried like that but it's not working and showing the same exception.

Comment: That's because you should not escape the character if it is inside a `CDATA` section. That's *either/or*, not *and*.

Comment: Can you post the solution for this

Comment: I tried to find an appropriate duplicate instead.

Comment: None of the option is not working so I used <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="string('>')"/>.